# IntelliJ keeps resetting my Java settings every time I re-import gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have found several similar reports involving mvn, but none with Gradle. Here's the issue.

I go to File->Project Structure->Project and change Project SDK to 11 and Project Language Level to 10. I hit apply, errors go away.

I refresh Gradle Project, check File->Project Structure->Project and it's Project SDK is set to 8 and Project Language Level to 6.

So after reading the problems I found here on stackoverflow, here is my build.gradle.

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
    id 'application'

    // Apply the groovy plugin to also add support for Groovy (needed for Spock)
    id 'groovy'

    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.2.RELEASE'
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.4.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.2'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // Use the latest Groovy version for Spock testing
    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.4'

    // Use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework even with Java
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
}

// Define the main class for the application
mainClassName = 'manage.App'

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

task deploy(dependsOn: 'build', type: Copy) {
    from bootJar.archivePath
    into "/opt/heavyweight"
}
```

Refresh. It still resets my project settings.

Here's gradle settings:

[image: Gradle Settings]

Please help.

```
thomas@office-workstation:/opt/gradle4$ bin/gradle -version
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/opt/gradle-4.10.2/lib/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-09-19 18:10:15 UTC
Revision:     b4d8d5d170bb4ba516e88d7fe5647e2323d791dd

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          11 (Oracle Corporation 11+28)
OS:           Linux 4.18.0-14-generic amd64

thomas@office-workstation:/opt/gradle4$
```

Answer (score 0):

That can happen sometimes. Project files can get quite complex, especially if you're working on a multi-module one.

First of all, I'd prefer always going with `Enum` constants.

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

Then, back-up `.idea/modules.xml`, delete it and re-import the Gradle project from the Gradle Tool Window.

---

As a last step, back up the project `*.iml` file, delete it, re-import as above.
Restart idea if the `*.iml` files does not get recreated.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Started by invalidating cache and restarting. No change. Followed your directions. No change. :(

Comment: Not even deleting all IML files?

Comment: @Thom could you post your Gradle build file? (or files, if multi module)

Comment: No, deleting the IML files didn't accomplish anything. I have placed the entire build.gradle in my question.

Comment: @Thom Check which JDK version you have assigned to Gradle, under Build tools.

Comment: 11. I'm also running gradle 4.x b/c 5.x generates its own error.

Comment: @Thom Uuuh, no idea then. What happens if you open the project from a clean IntelliJ installation (a portable one, obviously) ?

Comment: Works fine here. Try using more recent [Gradle version](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_version_install) (4.10 or newer). Can you build it from command line by Gradle using this language level for sources?

Comment: @Andrey I think he's already on Gradle 4.10+. What I'd like to know if it is Gradle Wrapper or not

Comment: @Andrey on 4.10. Added more gradle info to the question

Comment: @Thom switch to the Wrapper and let me know

Comment: Started with both wrapper settings. Some kind of version issue with Gradle 5. That's why I switched to using my onboard gradle 4 environment.

Comment: @Thom would be interesting to know which kinda error it was. The bundled Gradle wrapper shouldn't cause conflicts

Comment: This issue: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/340

Comment: @Thom I remember having issues with a certain Gradle Wrapper project on 2018.3. Give 2019.1 EAP a shot. It's pretty stable and I'm using it since the first day it was out. Many problems with Gradle have been solved.

Comment: Cool! When I started having this issue, I tried to find a place to check for updates, but couldn't find it. How do you get it to upgrade when it's not ready?

Comment: @Thom You can follow all the released versions via https://confluence.jetbrains.com/collector/pages.action?key=IDEADEV and you can download  the latest EAP version here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2019.1+EAP

Comment: @Thom I have a `wget --spider` script which I let run near the weekly release dates, and sometimes I'm able to get the packages even before they're released